# MATLAB Bisection method inaccurate

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble with implementing the bisection method in MATLAB.

I have to evaluate `x-tan(x) =  0` for my homework. When I evaluate on interval [-1,1] I get 0, which is correct, but I can not get the next root (approx 4.4934). I have tried other functions which seem to evaluate properly as well as other implementations which yield the same result (1.5708). This leads me to believe that `f=@(x) x-tan(x)` is not working properly.

My code for the bisection method is:

```
function root = bisection(a,b,max_tol, max_iter)
%set function handle here%
f = @(x) (x-tan(x));
    if(f(a)*f(b) > 0)
        disp ('reconfigure endpoints');
        return;
    end
iter = 1;
while(iter <= max_iter)
    mid = (b+a)/2;
    if (f(mid) == 0 || (b-a)/2 < max_tol)
        disp('Iterations: ');
        disp(iter);
        root = mid;
        return;
    end
    iter = iter + 1;
    if(sign(f(mid)) == sign(f(a)))
        a = mid;
    else
      b = mid;
    end
end
end
```

One interesting thing that I've been looking at is a plot of my intended function. It was created using `x=[-10:.01:10]; y=f(x); plot(x,y);`[image: MATLAB Plot of x-tan(x) on (-10,10)]

Comment: Please provide more details than just "I can not get the next root". Do you get an error? Or a an incorrect value? What specific arguments are you using? A well-written function would have default values for arguments such as `max_tol` and `max_iter`.

Comment: Also, do you know what the `if(f(a)*f(b) > 0)` block is for – is this entirely your own code? You might look at where the code is exiting and why it isn't returning a root when this block is triggered and why/if this block needs to exist? Also, how about roots to the left of the origin?

Comment: @horchler "I can not get to the next root" is explained when I say that the first root is 0, the next is 4.4934 and not supposed to be 1.5708. I am getting an incorrect result. As for default values, I'm not sure how to do that in MATLAB. Regarding the if-block you mention... that's a first check to verify that the endpoints aren't in a region without a root between them. It's the first step in any pseudocode I've seen for the bisection method. If it's triggered, there is no root between the endpoints.

Comment: You still haven't mentioned your inputs? So what happens if `a=4` and `b=5` then? The bisection method places certain assumptions on the behavior of the function between the bracketing values.